# I did not set swap memory, will that affect the way Ubuntu runs?

Tags: ram, swap

- My PC has 8Gb DDR3 RAM.
- I use Ubuntu 16.4.

I did not set swap memory due limitations of my HDD (which allows me only 4 active partitions).

Do I need swap? What difference does it make to my PC? What do I get from swap memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of SWAP is to extend your RAM using a special HDD partition or an file.

If the total of your memory usage won't reach to 8GB, the lack of SWAP partition won't affect you.

Note: If you would like to be able to hibernate your computer, then you should have a SWAP partition.

More info about SWAP can be found in [What Is a Linux SWAP Partition, And What Does It Do?](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/swap-partition/)